# How can I combine the information from these two dataframes?

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, recommender-system, dataframe

If one of my dataframes gives me some info about items:

```
itemId     property_1      property_2     property_n       Decision
    i1          88.90             NaN              0           Good
    i2          87.09    7.653800e+06              0            Bad
    i3          78.90    7.623800e+06              1           Good
    i4          93.02             NaN              1            Bad
...
```

And the other one gives me some info about how users interacted with the items:

```
userId        itemId      Decision
    u1            i1             0
    u1            i2             1
    u2            i1             1
    u2            i3             0
    u2            i4             1
    u3            i5             0
...
```

Can I combine them both to predict the `Decision` (converted to 0 and 1 in the first dataframe, obviously)? I can easily build a classification model for the first one and I could make a prediction similar to collaborative filtering in recommender systems based on the second dataframe. They both work well. But I want to combine the infos and hope for an even better prediction. How could I do that?

Comment: why don't you just use a natural join?

Comment: @bonfab would that be like merging the two? (sorry, I have 0 experience in SQL!). I thought about merging them, but then what would my feature columns look like? Initially I have just some numeric values for each itemId, but in the second dataframe I have multiple Decisions per item from different users...